# Sending mail and testing it locally for php project

Tags: php, email-client

I am doing email verification for my php project , for that I have written the code but the problem is how to check my mails are going to the desired location . Is there any way to send  arbitrary mail for checking my code on localhost.Basically I wanted to see my sent mail on localhost. I have xammp installed.

Comment: as per your COMMENTS..if you want to test the layout/link formation..why dont you send an email to urself so that u can have an idea what others are receiving..let me know the case

Comment: basically i want to test everything on localhost with no net connectivity.Is there any way to use an arbitary email client and sever which can be used on localhost

Comment: what you want to test ? template rendering? check HTML for the email template by running the file ..however the thing you are asking makes NO sense to me as I dont know without net connectivity how do you check your email?? One thing more For proper implementation you need to check it on LIVE..as your mail may looks different for different EMAIL CLIENTS(gmail,outlook etc)

Comment: once mailed send you actually cant check whether it received at another end or not...for this you need to ACTUALLY perform LIVE tests..you can only check whether your mail() function is returning true or false on execution

Comment: I want to set a local mail client for checking the sent mail just for checking whether the link given in sent mail works or not

Comment: you just copy/paste the URL formed in the template and check whether its desired action takes place or not..no need for email client for this stuff

Answer (score 0):

The mail() function usually doesn't work by default for things like WAMP. You will need to add details of your SMTP server to the php.ini file.

Here is a nice tutorial: http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Comment: for me this not the problem.There is no error in sending the mail.I just wanted to check locally where the mail goes and also i am sending a link for verification.I wanted to see the link on the web client side and check whether that link is working or not.Basically I Want To see MY SENT MAIL ON LOCALHOST

Answer (score 0):

**php.ini file:**    Search for mail function in that file and replace its content as follow.
[mail function]

; For Win32 only.

; http://php.net/smtp

SMTP = your serve’s host name. (ex.  mail.test.com)

; http://php.net/smtp-port

smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.

; http://php.net/sendmail-from

sendmail_from = Sender email Id .(ex. testing@gmail.com

Save the php.ini file.
Write code to send mail.

Test message

Hey its working!.. ..

‘;

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = ’MIME-Version: 1.0′ . ”\r\n”;
$headers .= ’Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1′ . ”\r\n”;

// Additional headers
$headers .= ’To: Receiver name ’ . ”\r\n”;
$headers .= ’From: Sender name ’ . ”\r\n”;

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

Comment: i have no problem in sending mail . i just wanted to see my sent mail as they are sent to arbitary emails .  I s there any way to have arbitary emails for checking the mails on localhost